# How to reduce code duplication in jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am a beginner to both web development and node.js. I am trying to build a very basic news website with node.js and express. In the home page, I hope to display some featured news, and in the page "news" I expect to display all the news.

It makes sense that the home page and the "news" page can share the jade code to display news. Using the same routes and db node.js functions to handle news listing in both places seems straightforward to me. I wonder whether there is a good way to share code and reduce code duplication in jade (perhaps like the concept "partial" in ruby on rails)?

Any help or reference links are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jade` has [`Includes`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a13):

```
html
  include includes/head
  body
    h1 My Site
    p Welcome to my super amazing site.
    include includes/foot
```

Also you can use [`Mixins`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#mixins) when possible, to reduce the amount of code you need to write:

```
mixin list
  ul
    li foo
    li bar
    li baz

h2 Groceries
mixin list
```

Comment: Thanks! If I use `Includes`, it seems that I need three jade files, one for home page, one for the "news" page, and the third one is used to display the list of news and is included by the first two. Btw, I have just scanned the link of `mixins`, and are `mixins` used like functions in other languages?

Comment: @jeff generally you can think of `jade `mixins as functions in other languages.

Comment: Une `extends` for your news page etc

Comment: For you general layout use Template Inheritance: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11 Also if you use mixins you can replace the 'mixin' keyword with '+' when initializing it. So in fardjad's code you can do <cod>+list</code> makes it a bit shorter.